# Escribir en presente de subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, conjugación

Is it correct to say “Me basta con que escribeme una vez al mes”? Given there's a *que* before the verb, shouldn't it be written in the present subjuntive (escríbame)?

Also, is *con* appropriate in this case?

Comment: Your sentence is not grammatically correct, but what exactly are you trying to say? What do you already know about the subjunctive?

Comment: Regarding the verb, I know that since escribir ends with -ir, it will be changed to an -a. Also, I'm not sure “con” fits the phrase.

Comment: I think he wants to say: "Me basta con que me escribas una vez al mes" (It is/will be enough for me if you write (to) me once a month), more or less equivalent to the imperative: "Escríbeme al menos una vez por mes" (Write (to) me at least once a month.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form for the sentence, if the intended meaning is "It is enough (for me) if you write (to me) once a month", is

> *Me basta con que me escribas una vez al mes.*

The verb form *escribas* is in the subjunctive mood, present tense, second person singular. The non-emphatic pronoun *me* must be proclitic (i. e. it must come before the verb) here, as in most cases. You use the enclitic pronouns (i. e. after the verb, and written as one word) in the imperative mood, for example:

> *Escríbeme una vez al mes.*

The subjunctive, as you see, very often appears within a subordinate phrase headed by the word *que* (such as *Me basta con que…*, *Te pido que…*, *Me gustaría mucho que…*). The imperative cannot go inside a subordinate like this.

Note well that *que* does **not** mean that the following verb must be in the subjunctive. That's not even a good rule of thumb for most cases.

*Escríbeme* is in the imperative mood, not the subjunctive. *Escríbame* is its formal equivalent (it's what you'd say to someone you're referring to as *usted*). Since *usted*, though second person, takes third-person verb forms, the formal imperative is formed using the subjunctive:

> *Escríbame pronto.* = "Write<sub>(formal)</sub> to me soon."
>   *Le pido que me escriba pronto.* = "I ask you<sub>(formal)</sub> to write to me soon."

Finally, in *Me basta con que me escribas…*, you can drop *con* and the meaning will be the same. You can also drop either one of the pronouns *me* and the meaning will be mostly the same as well.